# Update a column value based on priority SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to update a column `Paying` in `#temp` table value based on `priority` column value the following code shows how I am selecting from the table

```sql
SELECT * 
INTO #Temp
FROM
   (SELECT 
        FT.FeeTypeName, FSE.FeeAmount,
        ISNULL( FCD.FeeAmount, 0) AS Paid,
        (FSE.FeeAmount - ISNULL(FCD.FeeAmount, 0)) AS Due,
        FSE.SortOtder, 0 AS Paying 
    FROM 
        FEESETTINGS AS FS
    JOIN 
        FeeSettingsDetails AS FSE ON FSE.FK_FeeSettings = FS.ID_FeeSettings 
                                  AND FSE.Cancelled = 0
    JOIN 
        FeeType AS FT ON FT.ID_FeeType = FSE.FK_FeeType 
                      AND FT.Cancelled = 0
    LEFT JOIN 
        FeeCollection AS FC ON FC.FK_Program = FS.FK_Programs 
                            AND FC.FK_Student = 1
    LEFT JOIN 
        FeeCollectionDetails AS FCD ON FCD.FK_FeeCollection = FC.ID_FeeCollection 
                                    AND FCD.Cancelled = 0 
                                    AND FCD.FK_Type = FSE.FK_FeeType
    WHERE 
        FS.FK_Programs = 2
) AS T
```

and the below table represents result table `#temp`:

| Fee Type Name | Fee Amount | Paid Amount | Due | Priority | Paying |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2nd Semester Fee | 45000.00 | 20000.000 | 25000.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 1st Semester Fee | 35000.00 | 20000.000 | 15000.000 | 1 | 0 |
| Internal Exam fee | 1000.00 | 0.000 | 1000.000 | 2 | 0 |
| Annual Exam Fees | 2500.00 | 0.000 | 2500.000 | 3 | 0 |

If the user paying Amount **18500**  I want to update the column **paying** based on priority which give me  below table result.

What I am trying to select the details in a **temp** table and trying to update the column **Paying** but I have no idea how I will select the value to update each column can you help me find it out

```sql
UPDATE #Temp
SET Paying=(

)
```

Which will give me a result like this

| Fee Type Name | Fee Amount | Paid Amount | Due | Priority | Paying |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2nd Semester Fee | 45000.00 | 20000.000 | 25000.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 1st Semester Fee | 35000.00 | 20000.000 | 15000.000 | 1 | 15000 |
| Internal Exam fee | 1000.00 | 0.000 | 1000.000 | 2 | 1000 |
| Annual Exam Fees | 2500.00 | 0.000 | 2500.000 | 3 | 2500 |

Comment: Is this what you want? `UPDATE #Temp SET Paying = Due WHERE Priority > 0`

Comment: @MartinSamek No what i want is check the due and priority and if priority  1 have due then fill it first and go for next

Comment: is the `user paying Amount` always equal to total `Due` ?

Comment: @Squirrel not it can vary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need runnig total

```
declare @amount decimal(10,3) = 18500;

update t
set paying = p
from (
select *, 
   case when sum(Due) over(order by sortorder desc) <= @amount  then Due 
        when sum(Due) over(order by sortorder desc) - Due <= @amount then @amount - (sum(Due) over(order by sortorder desc) - Due)
        else 0 end p
from #Temp) t;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3b8de588c3eaac926ee05944ccd5d3e7)

You can substitute `sum(Due) over(order by sortorder desc) - Due` with a bit more verbose `sum(Due)  over(order by sortorder desc rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)` as well.